# How to write cost function formula from Andrew Ng assignment in Octave?

Tags: machine-learning, octave, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

My implementation (see below) gives the scalar value 3.18, which is not the right answer. The value should be 0.693. Where does my code deviate from the equation?

Here are the instructions to solve for the data to run the cost function  method in Octave:

```
data = load('ex2data1.txt');
X = data(:, [1, 2]); y = data(:, 3);
[m, n] = size(X);
X = [ones(m, 1) X];
initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
[cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y);
```

Here is the link on `ex2data`, in this package there is data: [data link](https://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/data/en-exercises-16.html).

The formula for the cost function is
[image: formula]

Here is the code I am using:

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

m = length(y); % number of training examples

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J = 0; %#ok<NASGU>
grad = zeros(size(theta)); %#ok<NASGU>

hx = sigmoid(X * theta)';
m = length(X);

J = sum(-y' * log(hx) - (1 - y')*log(1 - hx)) / m;

grad = X' * (hx - y) / m;

end
```

Here is the sigmoid function:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
g = 1/(1+exp(-z));
end
```

Comment: Please provide your `sigmoid` function too.

Comment: @rayryeng sure ..

Comment: You're using matrix multiplication (`*`), but your equation doesn't have any of those. Try using element-wise multiplication instead (`.*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sigmoid` function is incorrect.  The incoming data type is a vector but the operations you are using are performing matrix division.  This needs to be element-wise.

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
    g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));
end
```

By doing `1 / A` where `A` is an expression, you are in fact compute the **inverse** of `A`  Since inverses only exist for square matrices, this will compute the pseudo-inverse which is definitely not what you want.

You can keep most of your `costFunction` code the same as you're using the dot product.  I would get rid of the `sum` since that is implied with the dot product.  I'll mark my changes with comments:

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

m = length(y); % number of training examples

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
%J = 0; %#ok<NASGU> <-- Don't need to declare this as you'll create the variables later
%grad = zeros(size(theta)); %#ok<NASGU>

hx = sigmoid(X * theta);  % <-- Remove transpose
m = length(X);

J = (-y' * log(hx) - (1 - y')*log(1 - hx)) / m; % <-- Remove sum

grad = X' * (hx - y) / m;

end
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the answer, my sigmoid function was missing the scalar multiplication as you defined as  1./  the rest part of the cost function was right.  The point where you asked me about sigmoid function, i get to know yeah , i didnot checked that. again thank you very much sir ...i have be stuck from days in this.

Comment: also i have another question, why you said remove the sum ? in formula we have the summation of all iterations ?

Comment: @irfan the dot product is already doing the sum of the terms for you. You are not summing over iterations but the number of training examples. The iterations are done outside of this function. To find the sum of two vectors where each term is multiplied together, this is simply the definition of the dot product. The sum of the ground truth vector and hypothesis whose terms are multiplied together is already done by the dot product which you have done.

Comment: oh, absolutely yes ... i have run the iterations and yes sir it gave the same results. Thank you very much sir ..

Answer (score 2):

This is the code for the sigmoid function which I think you have made mistake in:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
   g = zeros(size(z));
   temp=1+exp(-1.*z);
   g=1./temp;
end


function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
   m = length(y); 
   J = 0;
   grad = zeros(size(theta));
   h=X*theta;
   xtemp=sigmoid(h);
   temp1=(-y'*log(xtemp));
   temp2=(1-y)'*log(1-xtemp);
   J=1/m*sum(temp1-temp2);
   grad=1/m*(X'*(xtemp-y));
end
```

And I think it should be (1-y)' as shown in temp2=(1-y)'

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's `(1 - y)'` vs `(1 - y')`. The key is the scalar subtraction.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the answer, my sigmoid function was missing the scalar multiplication as you defined as  1./  the rest part of the cost function was right.